# Pack/ jitter within a distance in a scatter plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to recreate this:
[image]

The basic elements are not difficult to recreate:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

colors = ["#CC5A43","#CC5A43","#2C324F","#2C324F","#5375D4","#5375D4"]

data = {
    "year": [2004, 2022, 2004, 2022, 2004, 2022],
    "countries" : [ "Denmark", "Denmark", "Norway", "Norway","Sweden", "Sweden",],
    "sites": [4,10,5,8,13,15]
}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values(['countries' ,'year' ], ascending=True ).reset_index(drop=True)

years = df.year
countries = df.countries.unique()
sites = df.sites


fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols= 2, nrows = 3, figsize=(5,5),facecolor = "#FFFFFF",subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))

for ax,site in zip(axes.ravel(), sites):
    # jitter the points
    r = 2*np.random.rand(site)
    theta = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(site)
    ax.scatter(theta,r, s= 100)
    ax.set_rmax(2.5)
    ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi / site)
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    #ax.grid(False)
    ax.spines['polar'].set_visible(False)

   
for ax, year in zip(axes[:,0], countries):
    ax.set_ylabel(year, rotation=0,size= 12,color = "#929EA7")
    ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.8, 0.5)

for ax, col in zip(axes[0], years):
    ax.set_title(col, x=0.5, y=1.2,color = "#929EA7")
```

which gives me:
[image]

The issue I have,is that the jitter is completely random, and therefore an already hard to read graph becomes even more unreadable.

I have tried the packed version for matplotlib:

```
    import random
sites= df.sites

class C():
    def __init__(self,r):
        self.N = len(r)
        self.x = np.ones((self.N,3))
        self.x[:,2] = r
        maxstep = 2*self.x[:,2].max()
        length = np.ceil(np.sqrt(self.N))
        grid = np.arange(0,length*maxstep,maxstep)
        gx,gy = np.meshgrid(grid,grid)
        self.x[:,0] = gx.flatten()[:self.N]
        self.x[:,1] = gy.flatten()[:self.N]
        self.x[:,:2] = self.x[:,:2] - np.mean(self.x[:,:2], axis=0)

        self.step = self.x[:,2].min()
        self.p = lambda x,y: np.sum((x**2+y**2)**2)
        self.E = self.energy()
        self.iter = 1.

    def minimize(self):
        while self.iter < 1000*self.N:
            for i in range(self.N):
                rand = np.random.randn(2)*self.step/self.iter
                self.x[i,:2] += rand
                e = self.energy()
                if (e < self.E and self.isvalid(i)):
                    self.E = e
                    self.iter = 1.
                else:
                    self.x[i,:2] -= rand
                    self.iter += 1.

    def energy(self):
        return self.p(self.x[:,0], self.x[:,1])

    def distance(self,x1,x2):
        return np.sqrt((x1[0]-x2[0])**2+(x1[1]-x2[1])**2)-x1[2]-x2[2]

    def isvalid(self, i):
        for j in range(self.N):
            if i!=j: 
                if self.distance(self.x[i,:], self.x[j,:]) < 0:
                    return False
        return True

    def plot(self, ax):
        for i in range(self.N):
            circ = plt.Circle(self.x[i,:2],4 )
            ax.add_patch(circ)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols= 2,nrows = 3, subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

for  site, ax in zip(sites, axes.ravel()):
    print(site+4, site)

    r = np.random.randint(0,15, size=site)

    c = C(r)

    #ax.axis("off")
    c.minimize()
    c.plot(ax)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
```

but in some cases it wont jitter the values (same with circlify):

[image]

Any ideas on how to properly jitter the circles so it resembles the original chart?